# How do I end a JavaScript while loop when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am working on an age guesser project to test my programming language skills on Java, Python, and JavaScript. Java and Python ran pretty solidly without much pain.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int age;
        int power;
        String response;
        age = 64;
        power = 5;
        while (true) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Are you ");
            System.out.print(age);
            System.out.print(" years old? Answer with 'Yes', 'Older' or 'Younger'. Nothing else.");
            response = input.next(); 
            if (response.equals("Yes")){
                System.out.print("Nice! You are ");
                System.out.print(age);
                break;
            }
            if (response.equals("Older")){
               age = age + (int)(Math.pow(2, power));
               power = power - 1;
            }
            if (response.equals("Younger")){
                age = age - (int)(Math.pow(2, power));
                power = power - 1;
            }
            if (power == -1){
                System.out.print("Nice! You are ");
                System.out.print(age);
                break;
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

```py
age = 64
power = 5
while True:
    response = input("Are you {0} years old? Answer with 'Yes', 'Older' or 'Younger'. Nothing else.".format(age))
    if response == "Yes":
        print("Nice! You are {0} years old!".format(age))
        break
    if response == "Older":
        age += (2**power)
        power -= 1
    if response == "Younger":
        age -= (2**power)
        power -= 1
    if power == -1:
        print("Nice! You are {0} years old!".format(age))
        break
```

Problem is with JavaScript not working. I tried with break first, then did research and figured out break wasn't working. After that I tried with a terminator number, in which the loop runs while the terminator number is at set value. Can someone explain what I did wrong with my JS code and also give the solution to this bug?

```js
let age = 64;
let power = 5;
let terminatornum = 4
while (terminatornum == 4) {
    let response = window.prompt("Are you " + age + " years old? Answer with 'Yes', 'Older' or 'Younger'. Nothing else.");
    if (response == "Yes") {
        console.log("Nice you are " + age + "years old!");
        terminatornum -= 1;
    } 
    if (response == "Older") {
        age += (2**power);
        power -= 1;
    }
    if (response == "Younger") {
        age -= (2**power);
        power -= 1;
    }
    if (power == -1) {
        console.log("Nice you are " + age + "years old!");
        terminatornum -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: *figured out that break wasn't working* -- Nonsense.  `break` works.  It always has.  Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: It didn't work since on the age guesser when the console log said I am 15 years old it went back to asking me if I am 64 years old..

Comment: It must work. Fundamental constructs like loops and `break` will *always* work exactly as they should. Always. You can count on that fact. Did you have one loop inside of another, and then broke from the inner loop? In that case, the outer loop will restart the inner one. Show the version that used `break`.

Comment: If you LIE to the age guesser, you might see this.  It wouldn'y have guessed 15 unless `power` was already 0.  If you lie and say "younger", then power will become -1, and it will think it succeeded.

Comment: ```js 
let age = 64;
let power = 5;
while (power >> -2) {
    let response = window.prompt("Are you " + age + " years old? Answer with 'Yes', 'Older' or 'Younger'. Nothing else.");
    if (response == "Yes") {
        console.log("Nice you are " + age + "years old!");
        break;
    } 
    if (response == "Older") {
        age += (2**power);
        power -= 1;
    }
    if (response == "Younger") {
        age -= (2**power);
        power -= 1;
    }
    if (power == -1) {
        console.log("Nice you are " + age + "years old!");
        break;
    }
}```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A straight port of your Python code works just fine:

```
let age = 64;
let power = 5;
while( true ) {
    let response = window.prompt("Are you " + age + " years old? Answer with 'Yes', 'Older' or 'Younger'. Nothing else.");
    if (response == "Yes") {
        console.log("Nice you are " + age + "years old!");
        break;
    } 
    if (response == "Older") {
        age += (2**power);
        power -= 1;
    }
    if (response == "Younger") {
        age -= (2**power);
        power -= 1;
    }
    if (power == -1) {
        console.log("Nice you are " + age + "years old!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to know where I went wrong